# Get Receiver Email Name if Email is Valid

Tags: php

I have created a code of module in which i am testing that receiver email exists or not by using

```
@fsockopen( $connectAddress, 25, $errno, $errstr );
```

and its returning valid and not valid response too

```
preg_match( '/^220/', $reply = fgets($connect, $this->TCP_BUFFER_SIZE))
```

But i just want to know that can i receive RECEIVER_NAME with the help of email account ?

Comment: What is `RECEIVER_NAME` supposed to mean?

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot check if an email address is real or not. You can only validate the address format.

Comment: @Seblor It depends on the recipient's email provider. Most of the major providers do provide a way to check for address validity, though.

Comment: @duskwuff ah thanks for the info. Though it may be dangerous to rely on that, if not all providers have implemented it.

Comment: What receiver_name? An email address isn't bound to one "receiver name", I could use the same email on different sites with different names

Comment: Hello thanks all for quick response, but RECEIVER_NAME means once i validate email , once i receive proper reply by ping then i also want to know what is the exact name of receiver?